# Multiple threads access a return method is it thread safe with a lock?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I am trying to access a method from multiple threads, I am unsure if this is thread safe. If it is not, what would be the most efficient way to make it safe?

I took into account everyone's insights my final product can be shown below, I have also opted to call recycle on the packet itself.

My packet pool class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Networking
{
    public class PacketPool
    {
        private Queue<Packet> pool = new Queue<Packet>();
        private readonly object instance = new object();

        public Packet CreatePacket(string method)
        {
            lock (instance)
                return pool.Count == 0 ? new Packet() { Pool = this } : 
                       pool.Dequeue();
        }

        public void Recycle(Packet packet)
        {
            lock(instance)
               pool.Enqueue(packet);
        }
    }
}
```

The Packet Class

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace Networking
{
    public class Packet 
    {
        public Protocol Proto = Protocol.Sequenced;
        public PacketFlags Flag = PacketFlags.None;
        public Fragment Fragmented = Fragment.NotFragged;
        public SendType SendType = SendType.Raw;
        public EndPoint RemoteEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        public byte[] Buffer = new byte[512];
        public int Count = 0;
        public int Ptr = 8;
        public int Bits { get; set; } = 0;
        public ushort Id = 0;
        public ushort Lead = 0;
        public PacketPool Pool;

        public void Recycle()
        {
            Bits = 0;

            if (Buffer.Length > 512)
                Array.Resize(ref Buffer, 512);

            Count = 0;
            Flag = PacketFlags.None;
            Fragmented = Fragment.NotFragged;
            Proto = Protocol.Sequenced;
            Ptr = 8;
            Lead = 0;
            SendType = SendType.Raw;
            Pool.Recycle(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Hoping that the solution above makes life easier.

Comment: This is pointed out in an answer, but to highlight it further,  `public Queue<Packet> pool = new Queue<Packet>(2000);` defeats the purpose of the `lock`. Anything with a reference to a `PacketPool` can enqueue or dequeue items without acquiring that lock because the `Queue` is exposed. That's not good, even aside from threading issues. If you make it `private` you ensure that only the methods within the class enqueue or dequeue items.

Comment: I will make those changes now :)

Comment: Why don't you use `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, which would basically make most of the code in your question go away in an instant... ;-)

Comment: I actually tried using ConcurrentQueue<T> right now I guess that the lock was fine just getting some really weird residual effects.

Comment: Well, i don't know what the residual effects are , but i guess they aren't directly related to ConcurrentQueue<T> itself. (Argh, just noticed a mistake in my previous comment. I meant to say "_most of the locking code_", not "_most of the code_". It would be hilarious if ConcurrentQueue<T> would magically subsitute the packet instance reset there...)

Comment: There are many lines of code inside the second lock statement. Do all of them need protection? You should hold a lock for the shortest duration possible, to reduce contention.

Answer (score 4):

The code you've shown looks threadsafe, as long as the packets themselves are not modified on seperate threads. You could also consider making the PacketPool class threadsafe perhaps, to save some precious locking time.

You could simplify it by replacing `Queue` with [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1).

Note that you are modifying the Packet sent into the `Recycle` method. I'd recommend to make the data objects immutable, to avoid unexpected behaviour.

```
public class PacketPool
{
    public ConcurrentQueue<Packet> pool = new ConcurrentQueue<Packet>(2000);

    public Packet CreatePacket(string method)
    {
        if (pool.TryDequeue(out Packet packet))
        {
            return packet;
        }

        return new Packet();
    }

    public void Recycle(Packet packet)
    {
        packet.Bits = 0;

        if (packet.Buffer.Length > 512)
            Array.Resize(ref packet.Buffer, 512);

        packet.Count = 0;
        packet.Flag = PacketFlags.None;
        packet.Fragmented = Fragment.NotFragged;
        packet.Proto = Protocol.Sequenced;
        packet.Ptr = 8;
        packet.Lead = 0;
        packet.SendType = SendType.Raw;
        pool.Enqueue(packet);
    }
}
```

Comment: They are edited on separate threads, for instance lets say thread 1 and thread 2 request a packet.. I presume that the pool will send thread 1 a new packet / or queued packet and thread 2 would do the same. Then thread 1 could edit the returned packet because thread 2 has its own to edit. Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. As long as they do not use the packet after calling `Recycle`, that sounds OK. (Because another thread may dequeue the same packet. Would be a shame if that packet is being modified by a seperate thread after recycling.) So this sharing may cause some headbreaking in the long run.

Comment: ^^ You are exactly point on with headbreaking.. This is exactly what is going on an I figured it was the lock that was allowing other packets to be modified. I have the packets recycling to reduce the GC if I was to create 17k packets a second anywhere from 1kb to 100mb well GC would go haywire. All in all thank you for your help I really appreciate it. I might try to reduce the threads and figure out where the packet is being modified.

Comment: Perhaps you can create a property 'recycled' on the 'Packet' class. Then set recycled to `true` on recycling and 'false' on creating. If any property of `Packet` is used when recycled is `true`, throw a `PacketRecycledException`. That may show where your packet is being used when it shouldn't.

Comment: Boom that was the greatest idea ever. Thank you found the issue .

Answer (score 1):

If the Packet  isn't shared across threads, then this is thread safe thanks to the locks.

Be careful with the public field pool. You could edit also that on thread unsafe.

Please note that a dedicated lock object is recommended, otherwise there *could* be a deadlock - e.g another process locks the public property Pool. Recommended to make the lock object private and use it only in that class (so one level up)

> When you synchronize thread access to a shared resource, lock on a dedicated object instance (for example, private readonly object balanceLock = new object();) or another instance that is unlikely to be used as a lock object by unrelated parts of the code. Avoid using the same lock object instance for different shared resources, as it might result in deadlock or lock contention.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: The thread that will create the packet will only use the packet. So I do not think its shared. I will fix the code above to use a dedicated object. Thank you -Levon

Comment: The changes have been made I believe this is correct.